# Calico Dual Stack Setup Issue: Service not able to access pod of other node

Tags: kubernetes, calico, cni

I am trying to create a muli-node cluster with dual stack IPv4/IPv6 support using calico cni. Below are the configurations details:

```
# for IPv4
master-node 192.168.122.163
worker-node 192.168.122.157

# for IPv6
master-node fd00:4000::1cd
worker-node fd00:4000::147
```

I have created the cluster using below command:

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=fd00:4000::1cd  --pod-network-cidr=1100::/48,192.168.0.0/16 --service-cidr=fd00:100::/112,172.20.0.0/16 --feature-gates="IPv6DualStack=true"
```

I have configured calico.yaml with the following parameters:

```
 "ipam": {
 
         "type": "calico-ipam",
 
         "assign_ipv4": "true",
 
         "assign_ipv6": "true"
 
     },
 
 IP6: autodetect
 
 CALICO_IPV6POOL_CIDR: 1100::/48
 
 FELIX_IPV6SUPPORT: true
```

Before setting ipvs mode in kube-proxy, I was able to curl the service using nodeport 32123.
But after setting ipvs mode in kube-proxy, I am not able to curl the service using nodeport and get the below error:

```
curl -6 http://[fd00:4000::147]:32123 -g

curl: (7) Failed connect to fd00:4000::147:32123; Connection refused
```

Below are the details of the routes:

```
#ip r

default via 192.168.122.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100

172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 blackhole 192.168.77.0/26 proto bird

192.168.77.1 dev calic79ff359580 scope link

192.168.77.2 dev cali520e698fdc9 scope link

192.168.77.3 dev calie981225789b scope link

192.168.122.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.163 metric 100

192.168.204.64/26 via 192.168.122.157 dev tunl0 proto bird onlink

 

#ip -6 r

unreachable ::/96 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium

1100::8188:7708:7a58:d338:4d00 dev calic79ff359580 metric 1024 pref medium

1100::8188:7708:7a58:d338:4d01 dev cali520e698fdc9 metric 1024 pref medium

1100::8188:7708:7a58:d338:4d02 dev calie981225789b metric 1024 pref medium blackhole 1100::8188:7708:7a58:d338:4d00/122 dev lo proto bird metric 1024 error -22 pref medium

1100::ff6c:c44e:2e86:9ed9:20c0/122 via fd00:4000::147 dev eth1 proto bird metric 1024 pref medium unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium

fd00:100::1 dev kube-ipvs0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium fd00:100::a dev kube-ipvs0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

fd00:100::4611 dev kube-ipvs0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium fd00:4000::1cd dev eth1 proto kernel metric 101 pref medium

fd00:4000::/64 dev eth1 proto ra metric 101 pref medium

fe80::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 101 pref medium

fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

fe80::/64 dev calic79ff359580 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

fe80::/64 dev cali520e698fdc9 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

fe80::/64 dev calie981225789b proto kernel metric 256 pref medium default via fe80::5054:ff:fe88:d08c dev eth1 proto ra metric 101 pref medium
```

Does anyone has a solution to this?

Comment: What port is your service listening on? Can you post the output of `kubectl get svc`?

Comment: So did IPv6 work before you switched to ipvs?

Comment: We have disabled firewalld on both nodes(master and worker).
Before setting ipvs mode in kube-proxy, I was able to curl the service using nodeip:nodeport 32123.

Comment: `# kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       kubernetes     ClusterIP   fd00:1      <none>        443/TCP                  171m
default       my-nginx-new   NodePort    fd00:4611   <none>        8080:32123/TCP           167m
kube-system   kube-dns       ClusterIP   fd00:a      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   171m`